# how to install sqlserver2005 evaluation on xp sp2 machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

**Duplicate**

> https://serverfault.com/questions/7541/how-to-install-sqlserver2005-evaluation-on-xp

---

Hi

I am unable to instal SQLSERVER2005 evaluation version on winXp service pack2 machine. iam getting the error such that error 87: dotnet framework 2.0 installation  and parameter incorrect.

Before run the sqlserver 2005 setup i hav installed .NET FRAMEWORK2.0 manually rather than sqlserver2005 suite.

vs2003 is also installed on my machine.

is it problem vs2003 installation before sqlserver2005??

Answer (score 2):

When you run the installer for SQLServer 2005, the first thing it does is to check if the installation prerequisites are present on the system. That portion of the installer should install a suitable version of .NET Framework 2.0 for SQL Server 2005. Please try installing the framework as a prerequisite to installing SQL.